# Writing a technical manual

Tags: headline-case

Currently a technical manual must be written by me concerning a software product. There exists a concrete question concerning the headlines.
Which uppercase / lowercase writing style can be seen as correct?

e.g.

either all initial letters uppercase

```
Machine Settings
Currency Exponent
```

or all intitial letters lowercase except the first one

```
Machine settings
Currency exponent
```

I am aware that specific technical abbreviations (e.g. ACK - ACKnowledgement) must not be written in lowercase. It is clear that also the initial letter of names (person, city, country ..) must not be written in lowercase.

Comment: Pick a style based on a manual (main choices are AP Style and Chicago Manual of Style.  Pick and stick with it. AP Style works well.

Comment: @Xanne AP and Chicago are only the "main" styles for general audiences in the U.S. corporate world, and the OP has not provided much detail about the environment, the audience, or the subject matter. I would probably recommend [IEEE Style](http://www.ieee.org/documents/style_manual.pdf) over either AP or Chicago for a technical manual.

Comment: Consult your organization's style guide. If it doesn't have one, check how others seem to capitalize titles in your organization. If that's not possible, choose the style you like. This is a style question and should be off-topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about writing style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Title Case](https://experience.sap.com/files/guidelines/References/text_cap.htm) would probably be appropriate for the headings.  It is when:

> The first character in all words capitalised, except for certain subsets defined by rules that are not universally standardised. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Case_styles))

Make sure you remain consistent throughout, and take note of the styling of any previous manuals in your company.

Comment: Title case is conventional in print, but sentence case is often preferred in online media because it is easier to read, and the OP does not specify the format. Ultimately, it is a matter of style, and you use whatever your editor tells you to use.

Comment: @choster okay, it sounds like it's only going to be used for the main titles, so readability shouldn't be too much of an issue.